How do I scrape results on a webpage based on different inputs in R?
I have a dataframe which gives me the tax code of firms (ma_thue).
structure(list(ma_thue = structure(c("0100106987", "0100111659", 
"0100736499", "0100101072", "0100101763", "0100407286", "0100100865", 
"0100107885", "0100110937", "0100107067"), format.stata = "%11s"), 
    tinh = structure(c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 
    101, 101), format.stata = "%8.0g"), huyen = structure(c(9, 
    9, 23, 11, 9, 9, 11, 5, 9, 9), format.stata = "%8.0g"), xa = structure(c(39, 
    41, 1, 7, 29, 41, 19, 5, 5, 29), format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    lhdn = structure(c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1), format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    namsxkd = structure(c(1960, 1977, 1993, 1995, 1993, 1993, 
    1990, 1956, 1990, 1961), format.stata = "%8.0g"), nganh_kd = structure(c(5231, 
    2221, 5231, 5149, 5190, 5511, 5151, 5149, 5511, 5511), format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    ld11 = structure(c(377, 46, 123, 1643, 124, 38, 138, 120, 
    127, 438), format.stata = "%12.0g"), ld12 = structure(c(325, 
    17, 92, 391, 72, 22, 47, 45, 65, 266), format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    ld13 = structure(c(363, 46, 122, 1646, 120, 37, 141, 120, 
    131, 534), format.stata = "%12.0g"), ld14 = structure(c(320, 
    17, 93, 391, 68, 22, 49, 45, 67, 340), format.stata = "%12.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

I would like to know the registered business address of each firm by web scraping this website: https://masothue.com/
For example, if I put into the search box the tax ID of the first firm (0100106987), this comes out

How do I scrape the results of this page (most importantly Dia Chi field) for each tax code in R?
Thank you.

Have you considered using RSelenium?  It allows you to find the entry box, search, and then extract whatever you get from the results.
